# Add buttons to ArrayList at the specifed index

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am trying to add a button to an ArrayList, but when I specify the index an error comes up saying the index is out of bounds.

I initiate the array like this:

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

I have an Integer variable "order" which indicates the priority of the button. The button should be the first value in the array when it has priority 0.

The exception comes up with the following statement:

```
buttons.add(order,btn);
```

EDIT:

The value of order is more than the size of the ArrayList. I am creating the buttons dynamically. How would I be able to specify the size of the array?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm 95% sure that it is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: You are trying to reach 200th floor where 199th floor doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for ArrayList add method ..... it tells what could be the reason...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int, E)

Probably value of order is more than the size of the ArrayList. Print value of order before adding it to the list it will help...

Comment: I see, how would I be able to do it when the size is dynamic?

Comment: Check size of array see if order is greater simply buttons.add(btn); this way btn will be added at the end

Comment: One thing that quickly comes to my mind is create a Wrapper class like ButtonWrapper which will have 2 fields, Order and Button and One Comparator which will compare order of 2 ButtonWrapper. Add instance of ButtonWrapper to array list and just before using it sort this arraylist based on order.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `add` an element at a given index if the index is greater than the `ArrayList`'s size. The documentation clearly states this I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The `.add(int index, E object)` method will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when:
`index < 0 || index > size()`.

Check the value of your order variable before calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

If u already know what will be the final size of the array i advise you to set the capacity when u create the array 
Like this : "ArrayList  buttons = new ArrayList (25);" being 25 the number of elements of your array, starting from  0 to index 24, to qvoid index out of bounds error i also advise u to populate your array,then u write buttons.add(index,element) at the specif index there is already an element what it will do is shift the existing element to the next position  (if the index of the element was 0 ,after adding will be 1),instead u should try buttons.set(index,element) in this way pre existing element will be replaced with the one u wish to add